# Friendlist to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to call a jQuery function and load the userinfo via load() into a div. This is my userlist:

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="profile"><b>Alex</b><br>Some infos...</a>
<a href="#" id="2" class="profile"><b>Barney</b><br>Some infos...</a>
<a href="#" id="3" class="profile"><b>Chris</b><br>Some infos...</a>
```

This is my first attempt:

```
$(".profile").click(function(){
$("#title").text(".profil b");
$("#profilediv").load("user.php?id="+#id);});
```

Of course this doesn't work.

What it should do:

1) Get the value (username) of the -tag inside the clicked profile-link and put it into the #title.

2) Send the userid to user.php and put teh content into the #profilediv

I don't know if this is the best way... maybe something like this would also work:

```
<a href="#" id="1,Alex" class="profile">Alex<br>Some infos...</a>
```

And then split the id into userid and username...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what correct parameters user.php should get? because `.load("user.php?id="+#id)` seems to have a syntax issue. It should rather be `.load("user.php?id=#"+this.id)` or `.load("user.php?id="+this.id)`

Comment: also, you could use `data` attributes to pass different values like `data-id="1" data-name="alex"` instead of `id="1,Alex"`, then get the values in your script like `var dataName = $(this).data("name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `data` attributes to your html like

```
<a href="#" data-id="1" data-name="Alex" class="profile"><b>Alex</b><br />Some infos...</a>
<a href="#" data-id="2" data-name="Barney" class="profile"><b>Barney</b><br />Some infos...</a>
<a href="#" data-id="3" data-name="Chris" class="profile"><b>Chris</b><br />Some infos...</a>
```

Then get the values into your script like

```
$(".profile").click(function () {
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#title").text(name);
    $("#profilediv").load("user.php?id=" + id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a function instead:

```
<a href="#" onClick='javascript:loadProfile("1","Alex");'>
    <b>Alex</b><br>Some infos...
</a>
<a href="#" onClick='javascript:loadProfile("2","Barney");'>
    <b>Barney</b><br>Some infos...
</a>
<a href="#" onClick='javascript:loadProfile("3","Chris");'>
    <b>Chris</b><br>Some infos...
</a>
```

and the javascript:

```
function loadProfile(id,name){
    $("#title").text(name);
    $("#profilediv").load("user.php?id="+ id);});
}
```